# change OwinContext dbContext on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, dbcontext

I need to run-time change the `dbContext` for `Request.GetOwinContext()` to use a specific `connectionString` but  it's not working.

I've a `dbContex` `class` to accept a default `connectionString` from `Web.Config` or a specified one like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("AuthEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(string sConnectionString)
        : base(sConnectionString, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string sConnectionString)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext test = new ApplicationDbContext(sConnectionString);
        return test;
    }

}
```

then when a new user is registering i've tried to change the Owin's default dbContext for one with a new connectionString like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("create")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(CreateUserBindingModel createUserModel)
{
     (...)

     //get the specific connectionString
     var connectionString = cService.GetCompanyConnectionString(createUserModel.Company);

     //generate new dbContext
     var appDbContext = ApplicationDbContext.Create(connectionString);

     //get OwinContext
     var context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();

     //replace the DbContext inside OwinContext
     context.Set<ApplicationDbContext>("ApplicationDbContext", appDbContext);

     (...)
}
```

until and including `appDbContext` everything works as expected but on debuging, after setting `context.Set<ApplicationDbContext>...` the `context` is still using the default one.

I've also tried using `var context = Request.GetOwinContext();` and setting directly as `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Set<ApplicationDbContext>("ApplicationDbContext", appDbContext);` and `Request.GetOwinContext().Set<ApplicationDbContext>("ApplicationDbContext", appDbContext);` but I always get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here was the first string I was trying to use when setting, so this line

```
context.Set<ApplicationDbContext>("ApplicationDbContext", appDbContext);
```

must be changed to

```
context.Set<ApplicationDbContext>(appDbContext);
```

Comment: I believe this is because `.Set<T>` is a Weakly Typed method?

Comment: Hi i have done the same but the usermanager is still using old dbcontext..can u help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315809/how-to-change-database-name-in-dbcontext-connection-string-at-runtime