# Owin ApplicationDbContext did not update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, owin

I want to change my connectionstring at runtime based on the code user enters at login screen. I did the following

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
 public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string scCode){
        return new ApplicationDbContext("name=GEContext_" + scCode);
    }
```

And at login i change the connectionstring as follows

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"] = model.SchoolCode;

                var appDbContext = ApplicationDbContext.Create(model.SchoolCode);
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set<ApplicationDbContext>(appDbContext);
 ....
   }
 }
}
```

Now it is still referring to the original database...what am i missing?

P.S. For a history/detail consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315809/how-to-change-database-name-in-dbcontext-connection-string-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I Got the Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315809/how-to-change-database-name-in-dbcontext-connection-string-at-runtime)

The problem was in ApplicationDbContext where we need to specify a default database whereas in my scenario that default database had to change.
So i changed it using

```
 var appDbContext = ApplicationDbContext.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"].ToString());//new ApplicationDbContext("name=GEContext", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"].ToString());

 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set<ApplicationDbContext>(appDbContext);
 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set<ApplicationUserManager>(new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>(appDbContext)));

 return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```